# Bulk insert with gridview using C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, insert

I'm using checkbox to select the rows in the gridview. How do I insert the muliple selected rows into the table opening the connection for only one time.

Comment: Why not use a for / foreach? You could use LINQ's "Where" clause, but it does a for loop in the background as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you postback, read all the checked rows and put the data into a `DataTable`.  You can then use a `SqlBulkCopy` object to push that `DataTable` into your database table.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS to write into hidden field when user (un)checks a checkbox or to perform ajax call to server with id checked row.